# Spring Boot JPA - Wrongly returning previous results for joined table data

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the classes below.

**ReportStyle** entity contains a set of **ReportStyleLine** entities, composition relationship.

When I call a method **getReportStyleForReportIdAndClientId(8, 0)** it returns the correct values for both the ReportStyle Entity and it's set of ReportStyleLines.

**However,** when I call the method a 2nd time with different parameters, so **getReportStyleForReportIdAndClientId(9, 0),** it is returning the correct results for the ReportStyle Entity but the set of **ReportStyleLines are the ones from the previous method call.**

The SQL and parameters from hibernate debug logs are correct.

What's really odd is that the expected number of ReportStyleLines for the first call is 21 and 2nd call is 19. The 2nd call is returning 19 records but they are the first 19 from the first call so wrong data but the correct number of records.

I don't have a lot of experience with JPA/hibernate so hope someone can help.
Here are the classes

**This code is in a Service class.** The result of the 2 lines is where the problem is.

```
    @Autowired
    ReportStyleService reportStyleService;
    
    public Path generateReport(Integer reportId, FastfieldFormSubmission formSubmission) throws Exception {
        
        ReportStyle reportStyle = reportStyleService.getReportStyleForReportIdAndClientId(8, 0);
        
        ReportStyle reportStyleJSEA = reportStyleService.getReportStyleForReportIdAndClientId(9, 0);
        
        ...
    }
```

**ReportStyleService**

```
@Service
public class ReportStyleService {

    @Autowired
    ReportStyleRepository reportStyleRepo;

    public ReportStyle getReportStyleForReportIdAndClientId(Integer reportId, Integer clientId) {

        return reportStyleRepo.findReportStyleByReportMasterIdAndClientMasterId(reportId, clientId);
    }

}
```

**ReportStyleRepository**

```
public interface ReportStyleRepository extends CrudRepository<ReportStyle, Integer> {

    public ReportStyle findReportStyleByReportMasterIdAndClientMasterId(@Param("reportMasterId") int reportMasterId, @Param("clientMasterId") int clientMasterId);

}
```

**ReportStyle** Most fields excluded for simplicity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ReportStyle")
public class ReportStyle {

    public ReportStyle() {

    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reportStyle", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private Set<ReportStyleLine> styleLines = new TreeSet<>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence-generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence-generator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "reportstyle_id_seq"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            })
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "reportMasterId", nullable = false)
    private Integer reportMasterId;

    @Column(name = "clientMasterId", nullable = false)
    private Integer clientMasterId;


    public Set<ReportStyleLine> getStyleLines() {
        return styleLines;
    }

    public void setStyleLines(Set<ReportStyleLine> styleLines) {
        this.styleLines = styleLines;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getReportMasterId() {
        return reportMasterId;
    }

    public void setReportMasterId(Integer reportMasterId) {
        this.reportMasterId = reportMasterId;
    }

    public Integer getClientMasterId() {
        return clientMasterId;
    }

    public void setClientMasterId(Integer clientMasterId) {
        this.clientMasterId = clientMasterId;
    }

}
```

**ReportStyleLine**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ReportStyleLine")
public class ReportStyleLine {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "reportStyleId", nullable = false)
    private ReportStyle reportStyle;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence-generator")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "sequence-generator", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "reportstyleline_id_seq"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                    @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
            })
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "propertyName", nullable = false)
    private String propertyName;

    @Column(name = "propertyValue", nullable = false)
    private String propertyValue;


    public ReportStyle getReportStyle() {
        return reportStyle;
    }

    public void setReportStyle(ReportStyle reportStyle) {
        this.reportStyle = reportStyle;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPropertyName() {
        return propertyName;
    }

    public void setPropertyName(String propertyName) {
        this.propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public String getPropertyValue() {
        return propertyValue;
    }

    public void setPropertyValue(String propertyValue) {
        this.propertyValue = propertyValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you create those records and how you load and compare them? So basically a full test case?

Comment: At the moment I have just created the records directly through an sql client not via application code. To see the issue I am just setting a break point on the 2 lines in generateReport method and inspecting the ReportStylelLines Set inside the 2 returned ReportStyles. When doing this I can see that the ReportStyleLines inside the 2nd ReportStyle have the incorrect values, they are the values from the first ReportStyle.

Comment: I'm thinking it might have something to do with the Autowiring and the Repository possibly still holding results from the last sql for some reason but can't figure it out.

Comment: That seems very unlikely. The repositories don't do caching of data. The underlying EntityManager does but this would be a huge bug in the JPA implementation which tend to be rather stable.

Comment: What do you see when you revert the order of calls? If it is some kind of caching you should now see the other data.

Comment: Are any manual calls to entity manager required around a simple findBy call like in the ReportStyleService class call where I am calling the Repository?

Comment: Yeah if I switch it just reverses the data. So which ever gets called first is what shows in the following calls. However like I said only for the joined data not the main table ReportStyle, it still gets the correct values, just child data is data from first call.

Comment: "Are any manual calls to entity manager required..." Nope. You can get some nasty surprises with the 1st level cache of JPA, but since you insert the data using SQL that shouldn't be relevant.